# How to get the index when adding something to NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

I need the indexes of my operations added to NSOperationQueue, And hope it works like this:

```
    @interface MyOperation : NSObject {
        NSInteger index;
        /* Do Something */
}
```

Following will set the index member of myOperation as the location of it in operationQueue.

```
[operationQueue addOperation:myOperation]
```

Edit:
Actually i use a NSMutableDictionary to store the indexes of operations as objects and operations' names as keys.Like this:

```
    NSNumber* indexOfOperationInQueue;
    NSMutableDictionary *dictionary;
    ...
    -(void) AddOperation {
        indexOfOperationInQueue = [NSNumber numberWithInt:value + 1];
        [dictionary setObject:indexOfOperationInQueue forKey:@"operation0"];
    }
```

operation cancelled, crosspond key and object deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have assigning an index to operations in a queue, is that as the queue is cleared, their index will change.  Why don't you just assign ordinal values to them.

Add a super class for your operations with a class variable for the next index, and a method like

```
- (void) addToOperationQueue:(NSOperationQueue)queue;
```

Which sets the index value from the class variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can add each operation you create using NSOperationQueue to NSMutableArray then access operations from this array.